# How to test function level authorization in function app for local development?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I want to secure this function using function level authorization for local development. How can I frame the endpoint for this function?

```
 public static class FunctionLevel
 {
     [FunctionName("FunctionLevel")]
     public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",  Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
     {
         //code
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

For this is not supported, you could get this from this doc: [API key authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=csharp#api-key-authorization). 
There is a note here:

> When running functions locally, authorization is disabled regardless
>   of the specified authorization level setting. After publishing to
>   Azure, the authLevel setting in your trigger is enforced. Keys are
>   still required when running locally in a container.

So if you want to test `AuthorizationLevel` , you have to deploy you function to azure then use the auth key.

Comment: If this could help you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks！

Answer (score -1):

As your function is returning a `IActionResult` I understand that you are using Asp.net. So I suggest you to use`Asp.Net Identity` with `[Authorize()]` attribute.

You can get more information about on the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/